# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: No document to update. Can only update document if I hard code the document id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Hey for my current project I have a component that is able to create a user and add it into the database with

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).
```

I am trying to create another component that will be able to edit the current user that is logged in. I am getting this error whenever I run the function below in my button

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError:
No document to update: projects/teamh-test-tien/databases/(default)/documents/users/6BKmEeZeoXNYpgfM6ms6WbgH5as1.
```

The function only works when I hard code the document id and replace it with the user.uid for ex.

```
const profileRef = doc(db, "users", '6BKmEeZeoXNYpgfM6ms6WbgH5as1');
```

How would I be able to grab the document id then? I assumed the user.uid specified which document has that user id.

```
const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const profileRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
    // console.log('event--->', e);
    console.log('user id --->', user.uid);
    console.log('profileRef--->', profileRef);

    const profileDoc = await getDoc(profileRef).catch((error) =>
      console.error(error)
    );
    if (!profileDoc) {
      console.error('No document found for this user ID');
      return;
    }
    console.log('profileDoc--->', profileDoc);
    // const profile = await getDoc(profileRef);
    // console.log('profile--->', profile.data());

    await updateDoc(profileRef, {
      name,
      // name: name,
    }).then(() => console.log('updated!', auth.currentUser.displayName));
  };
```

This is my db structure:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2EsB.png)

This is how I create users and add it into the db:

```
const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
  try {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    const user = res.user;
    // console.log('user created', user)
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      uid: user.uid,
      name,
      authProvider: "local",
      email,
    });
    console.log('user auth', auth.currentUser)
    await updateProfile(user,{
      displayName: name,
    })
    await user.reload()
    console.log('user updated', user)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert(err.message);
  }
};
```

I've tried this which creates a new doc that would be the specific user.uid that was created when you

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).
```

```
// const handleUpdates = async (e) => {
  //  e.preventDefault()
  //   const profileRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
  //  await setDoc(profileRef, {
  //     name,
  //  }, { merge: true }).then(() => console.log('updated!', auth.currentUser.displayName))
  // };
```

[This is how the handleUpdates function work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOCmv.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a document's ID when adding it, use the `setDoc()` method instead...

```js
await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
  name,
  authProvider: "local",
  email,
});
```

This will allow you to retrieve documents by the auth user `uid`.

For more information, see [Add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

> When you use `set()` to create a document, you must specify an ID for the document to create

Using `addDoc()` auto-generates an ID which won't match your user `uid` properties.

Comment: Wow it was that simple I appreciate the help regardless